# ExpandableListView Com Formulario

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como posso usar uma ExpandableListView com um formulário ao invés de apenas texto.  Ao expandir a ExpandableListView ao invés de vir varia linhas com apenas textos eu possa colocar varios edittext diferentes para preenchimento. Gostaria de usar para dividir tipos de dados como primeira "aba" clientes segunda endereço. Espero ter sido claro na minha duvida.

Comment: É possível... Mas qual a necessidade de ser um `ExpandableListView`? Você poderia, por exemplo, criar um layout "escondido" abaixo de cada sessão do formulário e animar de acordo com o toque no componente

Comment: @sicachester bem não teria bem que ser uma  expandableListView mas como não tenho muito conhecimento em android achei que seria a solução mais simples, pois não quero ter que trabalhar com mais de uma activity para tratar esses editext. Caso tenha outra solução estou a ouvir. Só não quero que o usuário tenha que rolar um formulário muito grande, por isso gostaria de dividir.

Comment: Respondi com uma solução! Veja se atende

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer com o [TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html), mas está disponível só na API 19.

Uma solução, seria algo mais ou menos assim

1- No seu layout, coloque dentro de algum container (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout etc.) o que você quer esconder/mostrar. Você pode definir o clique para o componente inteiro, ou com um botão, como você preferir:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/touchAreaRelativeTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btTouchToOpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toque para abrir" />

    <!-- Layout a ficar escondido -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearOpen"
        android:layout_below="@id/btTouchToOpen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Titulo"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/etOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearOne"
            android:id="@+id/linearTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Titulo"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/etTwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

No seu Fragment ou Activity:

```
private RelativeLayout linearAction;
private int valueHeight;

...

linearAction = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearOpen);

//Definindo a altura do seu componente como 0.
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsList = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) linearAction.getLayoutParams();
if (paramsList != null)
    paramsList.height = 0;

//Retendo a altura do seu componente para a animação
valueHeight = linearAction.getHeight();
if (valueHeight == 0f) {
    linearAction.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    valueHeight = linearAction.getMeasuredHeight();
}

/*
* Aqui você pode utilizar seu proprio tempo de animação. Mas o Android já tem inteiros definidos para isso.
* sendo: config_shortAnimTime, config_mediumAnimTime e config_longAnimTime
*/
final int animationTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

Button btOpenView = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btTouchToOpen);
btOpenView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        animateViewHeight(valueHeight, linearAction, animationTime);
    }
});

...  

/**
 * Animando a altura do seu componente
 *
 * @param deltaToAnimate Tamanho a ser animado
 * @param view           View para fazer a animação
 * @param animationTime  Tempo de duração da animação
 */
private void animateViewHeight(final int deltaToAnimate, final View view, int animationTime) {

    //Verificando se a view já está aberta.
    final boolean isViewToAnimateShowed = Boolean.valueOf((String) view.getTag());

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(deltaToAnimate);
    animator.setDuration(animationTime);
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                                       int finalValue;
                                       //Caso esteja aberta, faz a animacao para fecha-la
                                       if (isViewToAnimateShowed)
                                           finalValue = deltaToAnimate - Math.round(animation.getAnimatedFraction() * deltaToAnimate);
                                       else
                                           finalValue = Math.round(animation.getAnimatedFraction() * deltaToAnimate);

                                       if (params != null) {
                                           params.height = finalValue;
                                           view.setLayoutParams(params);
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
    );
    animator.start();

    //Informando se a view esta aberta ou não
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(!isViewToAnimateShowed));
}
```